First return time for interval exchange transformation
I'm looking at an interval exchange transformation $T_d:[0,15]\to[0,15]$ and want to show that for a closed subinterval $I$, the first return time $w(x)$ is well defined, except for maybe a finite number of points that is smaller than the number of subintervals created by $T$.
I've tried visually to understand why it might not be well defined for a point but failed. In different colours, I put the subintervals and where they get shifted to under iteration of $T$. On the side, I wrote which part of my interval $I$ gets its first return in that iteration; however, it covers all of $I$ with no point ill-defined.
My question is: how do I get an ill-defined point?
[Graphic]1
EDIT: Okay, so apparently I've managed to create some points that won't return, but I'm not fully sure I understand what happens there. See graphic 2

What do you mean by "time" in this context? Normally, it would be always 1. Maybe you do not really mean time but point?

Sorry if that was imprecise, for a given point $x\in I$ it's minimal return time is the minimal number of iterations (say t) of $T$ such that $T^t(x)$ is again in the chosen interval $I$. So in my little graphic I did 5 iterations after which all subintervals returned to their initial position, so $t\leq 5; \forall x$

Then it depends on the subinterval.

Well yeah, but how would I construct an interval that has a point where the first return time of that point is ill defined?
